# How to compress a Pixmap / use cim files in android?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How can I compress a LibGDX Pixmap? I want to save it on the disk, but it uses about 4MB, which is way to much and takes like forever to save it.

```
final Pixmap pixmap = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, w, h);
FileHandle screenshot = Gdx.files.local("something.png");
PixmapIO.writePNG(screenshot, pixmap);
```

I saw that there is a `PixmapIO.writeCIM`, which is quite fast and the output is quite small.

Am I able to display the something.cim file in Android? The [docu](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/PixmapIO.html) says, that cim should only be used within libgdx. Arguing that this is the old documentation, maybe there is something new?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=8947

```
  int w = p.getWidth();
  int h = p.getHeight();

  int[] pixels = new int[w * h];      
  for (int y=0; y<h; y++) {
     for (int x=0; x<w; x++) {
        //convert RGBA to RGB
        int value = p.getPixel(x, y);
        int R = ((value & 0xff000000) >>> 24);
        int G = ((value & 0x00ff0000) >>> 16);
        int B = ((value & 0x0000ff00) >>> 8);
        int A = ((value & 0x000000ff));

        int i = x + (y * w);
        pixels[ i ] = (A << 24) | (R << 16) | (G << 8) | B;
     }
  }

  Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
  b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, handle.write(false));
```

Comment: Hey this is great, but this solution doesn't work for Desktop project right? Is there a way to do this using pure java code?

Comment: The link I posted contains a way to create a BufferedImage. Then you can use: File f = new File("MyFile.jpg"); ImageIO.write(img, "JPEG", f); to create a JPEG